# Web Server : retrieve POST data values

Tags: java, regex, post, webserver

I'd like to get the value of a specific key when my web server detects a POST request.

The best method I found is :

```
String content = request.getContent();
```

Example of POST data : field1=some-data&field2=other-data

I need to get : "some-data" from a given field "field1"

I tried to use :

```
String value = request.getParameter("field1");
```

But it works only if I pass my data into the URL ..

I wonder if I should use regex. If it is the case, what is the best pattern ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of web server are you using?

Comment: I am using "Simple Web Server"
http://simpleweb.sourceforge.net/index.php

Comment: Are you [sure](http://www.simpleframework.org/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/http/Request.html#getParameter(java.lang.String)) you're doing what you think you are? Are you using `PUT` (are you sure)?

Comment: Yes, I can find POST data in the body of the request, but there is no method to get a specific key.., for example : 
"data1=mydata&name=pseudo"